# Running two threads which are dependent on each other in a loop

Tags: python, multithreading

I need to know how to write a program that runs two threads:
1. a thread the updates the position(values) of an object 
2. a thread that runs two methods in it based on the values from the first thread
All of this in a loop

This is the current code that I have and I want to changed as I described, not that the value are form the valueList and the activate(valueList) is a method that contains several smaller methods in it. If you don't mind i would love to have an example to solving this.Thanks

```
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(('59.191.193.42',5555))


screenw = 0
screenh = 0
while 1:
    client_socket.send("loc\n")
    data = client_socket.recv(8192)
    valueList = data.split()

    if (not(valueList[-1] == "eom" and valueList[0] == "start")):
        #print "continuing.."
            continue

        if(screenw != int(valueList[2])):
            screenw = int(valueList[2])
            screenh = int(valueList[3])

    activate(valueList)
```

Comment: It is not clear why you want this to be multi-threaded. Do you expect `activate` to take a long time? If so, what do you want to happen when handling the previously received valueList is still in progress when the next one arrives?

Comment: Only use multithreading if absolutely necessary -- you're adding a lot of complexity to a seemingly simple problem.

Comment: @TimoKluck to compare the values.because in the actiavte(valueList) method contains two methods that moves a robot based on the changes of valueList. The problem i have with the current code is that the values are passed down too quickly that my robot repeats the same motion for some time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have pointed out, It doesn't look like threading is actually going to solve your problem. Especially because Python code is subject to the [Global Interpreter Lock](http://docs.python.org/c-api/init.html#threads), which basically means theading will only help you if your code is IO-bound (reading large files from disk, waiting on a slow network connection, etc). If your program is CPU-bound and you really want to take advantage of parallel processing, [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) is the way to go. With multiprocessing, you trade some memory overhead and a little latency (when the process is created and during inter-process communication) for the ability to take advantage of multi-core CPUs.

Just on the off chance that parallel processing does turn out to be useful for your program, or you're just curious, I present the following code sample. Disclaimer, I haven't so much as tried to import this module, so consider it pseudocode.

```
import socket
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Value
from ctypes import c_bool

HOST = '198.51.100.0'
PORT = 8080

# This function will be run in a child process
def update_proc(data_queue, update_queue, quit_flag):
    while not quit_flag.value:
        data = data_queue.get()
        # do something with the data...
        update_queue.put(data)
    print "Closing child update process"

# This function will be run in a child process
def activate_proc(update_queue, quit_flag):
    while not quit_flag.value:
        data = update_queue.get()
        # do something with the data...
    print "Closing child activate process"

# main process begins execution here, if module is run from the terminal
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Connect to remote host over TCP
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client.connect((HOST,PORT))

    # Set up a Queue to pass data to the update process, and another one
    # for the two children to communicate
    data_queue = Queue()
    update_queue = Queue()

    # The quit_flag Value is a *very* primitive way to signal the child 
    # processes to quit. I'm sure there are better ways to do this, but I'm 
    # tired and can't think of any right now.
    quit_flag = Value(c_bool, False)

    # Create two child processes, pass a reference to the Queue to each
    update = Process(target=update_proc, args=(data_queue, update_queue, quit_flag))
    activate = Process(target=activate_proc, args=(update_queue, quit_flag))

    update.start()
    activate.start()

    # Read data from the TCP socket, push it onto the data_queue
    while True:
        client.sendall("loc\n")
        data = client.recv(8192)
        if not data:
            print "network connection closed by client"
            break
        data_queue.put(data)

    # Join with child processes before closing
    print "All done, closing child processes"
    update.join()
    activate.join()
```

Comment: what if the data that is passed down contains many values how do i split them and how do i call the values? i am not familiar with queue

Comment: "what if the data that is passed down contains many values how do i split them" There are a ton of data structures that would work for this sort of thing, lists and tuples jump out at me. You should read http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html , it is very helpful. 

"how do I call the values?" I'm not sure what you mean here, but Python has first-class functions so you can add a bunch of functions to a list. If you want more details I can edit my answer.

The docs for the Queue structure are here: http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue

Comment: to be clear, the 'data' variable that is being pushed and popped from the Queue in my example could be anything. It could be a list of values, a dictionary mapping, a function, anything.