# How the best way to update multiple Python files that are executing under a Pool of processes

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm developing a system where I'll need execute many Python scripts at same time. I'm using this code to do it:

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool

processes = ('grabber.py', 'mailer.py', 'updater.py')


def run_process(process):
    os.system('python {}'.format(process))


pool = Pool(processes=3)
pool.map(run_process, processes)
```

This code is useful and solve my problem, but the script 'updater.py' is responsible to update the other codes 'grabber.py' and 'mailer.py' doing this steps:

1 - Try to download the news scripts (grabber and mailer) with updates from a remote server
2 - Make a Backup of current scripts
3 - Stop grabber.py and mailer.py
4 - Replace the scripts
5 - Reexecute them again

But, I'm thinking about my scenario. I'm using a Pool of processes to run my scripts. What the best way to sinalize my Pool Processes about this update Process and stop mailer and grabber?

Thank you!

Comment: If `updater` updates the other scripts, run that first before you run other scripts in a `Pool`.

Comment: See this:https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

Comment: And this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/how-to-use-threading-in-python

Comment: @RockyLi thank you for your answer! So, the updater needs to be executed at same time, because, the scripts can be updated any time. For example,the programmer can add a new routine in grabber.py, save and put into a remote server. Then, in a system, a support guy will sinalize that a new update will available ( updater will ask for a webservice of new updates are coming) and execute the download of script and to do the steps mentioned above...

Comment: I still don't see why they can't be executed sequentially. Given system update, updater runs, after it finishes, everything else runs in a sequential manner, what's the problem? You don't need to go in there and manually run other things, it's still in one script.

Comment: But, when update execute overwrite the old script for the new script, a overwrite system error can occur?

Comment: I think it will make it worse if threads are dependent. So , you can see this example how they solve it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12620748/running-two-threads-which-are-dependent-on-each-other-in-a-loop

Answer (score 0):

You can  try this way:

```
import threading
from time import sleep

threading.Thread(target='updater.py').start()
sleep(0.01)
threading.Thread(target='grabber.py').start()
sleep(0.01)
threading.Thread(target='mailer.py').start()
sleep(0.01)
```